# iOS enterprise application crashing on iOS 12

Tags: ios, xcode, hockeyapp, ios12, ios-enterprise

I have an Enterprise application hosted in HockeyApp.

The app is signed with Enterprise certificate and provisioning profile. I checked the expiration dates of both. Those are not expired.

When I am downloading the app in iOS 12, it crashes as soon as it opens. But works fine in lower iOS versions.

Here is the log i got through Xcode->Windows->Devices and Simulators:

**Reason: Fence-hang-PROCESSNAME: 574ms handling fence, blown-fence (fence duration=575ms)**

Comment: As the error message says, it has nothing to do with provision profile. Your application is running out of memory in the iOS 12 for some reason. I suggest you run the instruments and check where it goes wrong.

Comment: If that is the case, the app should crash while in debug mode as well. But, it is working fine in debug mode.

Comment: Has anybody face the same issue with enterprise application?

Comment: @chandvoid I'm facing same problem and not able to find the solution.